# Can I successfully call SKStoreReviewController.requestReview() if a user's already rated my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I would like to prompt my users to rate my iOS app.  I could not figure out if the in-app review prompt would display if a user has already rated my app (either in the App Store or from an in-app review prompt) - does anyone know?

Furthermore, in [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/system-capabilities/ratings-and-reviews/), Apple suggests that we allow a week or two in between attempts at in-app review prompts.  Is this a hard-limit imposed at an OS level that would prevent in-app review requests from occurring, or just a guideline?

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?